# how to find similarity between two question even though the words are differentiate

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, sentence-similarity

is there is any way to find the meaning of the string is similar or not,,, even though the words in the string are differentiated

Till now i tried fuzzy-wuzzy,levenstein distance,cosine similarity to match the string but all are matches the words not the meaning of the words

```
Str1 = "what are types of negotiation"
Str2 = "what are advantages of negotiation"
Str3 = "what are categories of negotiation"
Ratio = fuzz.ratio(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower())
Partial_Ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(Str1.lower(),Str2.lower())
Token_Sort_Ratio = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Str1,Str2)
Ratio1 = fuzz.ratio(Str1.lower(),Str3.lower())
Partial_Ratio1 = fuzz.partial_ratio(Str1.lower(),Str3.lower())
Token_Sort_Ratio1 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Str1,Str3)
print("fuzzywuzzy")
print(Str1," ",Str2," ",Ratio)
print(Str1," ",Str2," ",Partial_Ratio)
print(Str1," ",Str2," ",Token_Sort_Ratio)
print(Str1," ",Str3," ",Ratio1)
print(Str1," ",Str3," ",Partial_Ratio1)
print(Str1," ",Str3," ",Token_Sort_Ratio1)
print("levenshtein ratio")
Ratio = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1,Str2,ratio_calc = True)
Ratio1 = levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(Str1,Str3,ratio_calc = True)
print(Str1," ",Str2," ",Ratio)
print(Str1," ",Str3," ",Ratio)

output:
fuzzywuzzy
what are types of negotiation   what are advantages of negotiation   86
what are types of negotiation   what are advantages of negotiation   76
what are types of negotiation   what are advantages of negotiation   73
what are types of negotiation   what are categories of negotiation   86
what are types of negotiation   what are categories of negotiation   76
what are types of negotiation   what are categories of negotiation   73
levenshtein ratio
what are types of negotiation   what are advantages of negotiation               
0.8571428571428571
what are types of negotiation   what are categories of negotiation       
0.8571428571428571



expected output:
"what are the types of negotiation skill?"
"what are the categories in negotiation skill?"
output:similar
"what are the types of negotiation skill?"
"what are the advantages of negotiation skill?"
output:not similar
```

Comment: simply:Is there any way to find the similarity of the meaning of two strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to score the semantic similarity of two strings.

Fuzzy-wuzzy and Levenshtein distance score only characters distance.

You need to account **semantic** information. So, you need a semantic representation for your string.

Maybe a simple but effective method consists in:

1. Compute two vectors which represent your two strings, using pretrained word embeddings for your language (eg FastText - get_sentence_vector https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html#model-object)
2. Compute cosine similarity between two vectors (1: equal strings; 0: really different strings).

Surely, there are better and more complex methods.
To deeply understand this subject, I suggest this post (https://medium.com/@adriensieg/text-similarities-da019229c894), which is rich of explanations and code implementations.

Comment: tnx a lot it's really help me to understand the core of the subject

Comment: Might would get better results if you use Universal Sentence Encoder for step 1: https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2